# XTerm buffers output when reading from fifo

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, xterm, fifo

I have an xterm window that I would like to continually display the output of a named pipe.  However, there seems to be some buffering occurring, and I can't find where it is happening.

I open two terminals.  In the first, I make a pipe and watch for anything sent to it.

```
mkfifo pipe
tail -f pipe
```

On the second terminal, I send two messages through the pipe, from a single process, separated by some time.  I use `stdbuf` to make sure that the output of the command is unbuffered.

```
stdbuf -o0 bash -c 'echo hi; sleep 5; echo bye' > pipe
```

This works as expected, with the first terminal printing `hi`, then printing `bye` five seconds later.

However, if I run the `tail -f pipe` inside an xterm window, then the messages do not appear until the program exits.  Clearly, there is some buffering being done, but I cannot find where it is.  Is there a way to prevent xterm from buffering the output of programs?

My "normal terminal" uses PuTTY, ssh-ed from Windows 7 to Linux machine.  On the Linux machine, `uname -a` returns `Linux hostname 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, and `xterm -v` returns `XTerm(278)`.

Comment: This sounds very odd. Can you give some more details about how you're invoking the xterm? Sounds like it may be running a different shell, or there's something in your .bashrc or .profile which is setting a different environment. (Does the output of the 'env' command differ between the terminal and xterm?)

Answer (score 0):

On my tests, the buffering only happens for the first run of the bash script. So

```
bash -c 'echo' > pipe; bash -c 'echo hi; sleep 5; echo bye' > pipe
```

does pretty much what you want, but with an extra newline at the top. (I didn't even need stdbuf).